# express4 reusing mongodb handle

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am new to javascript and nodejs programming. I am trying to connect mongodb in express framework but like to keep code modular. I have below code written. I am using express version 4.14.0 and mongodb driver 2.2.27 version and nodejs v6.10.3

```
//app.js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var index = require('./routes/index');
app.use('/', index);
app.listen(3000);

//routes/index.js
var router = require('express').Router();
var anotherfile = require('../controllers/anotherfile');

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
        res.send('Connected');
});    
module.exports = router;

//controllers/db.js
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var connectionString = 'mongodb://user:password@127.0.0.1:27017/testdb';
var _db;

MongoClient.connect(connectionString, function(err, db) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('Error: ', err);
  } else {
    console.log('Connected!');
    _db = db;
    console.log("_db",_db);
  }
});

module.exports.getDb = function() {
  return _db;
}

//controllers/anotherfile.js
var connect = require('./db.js');
var db1 = connect.getDb();
console.log("print db1",db1);
```

What I want from above code is access to db handle in anotherfile.js. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

To keep the code modular you should keep the database functions in a separate file and then access those function from other your `anotherfile.js`. This way you can use that database function file for other projects as well.

**mongoConfig.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
module.exports = router;
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var uri = '<MongoDB server path>';

module.exports.insert = function(collectionName, json, callback) {
  mongo.MongoClient.connect(uri, function(err, db) {
    if (!err) {

    } else {

    }
  });
};

module.exports.retrieve = function(collectionName, json, callback) {
  mongo.MongoClient.connect(uri, function(err, db) {
    if (!err) {

    } else {

    }
  });
};
```

Your code in server.js.

**server.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var index = require('./routes/index');
app.use('/', index);
app.listen(3000);

//routes/index.js
var router = require('express').Router();
var anotherfile = require('../controllers/anotherfile');

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('Connected');
});
```

Then,

**anotherfile.js**

```
var Mongo = require('./mongoConfig');.
Mongo.insert();
Mongo.retrieve();
```

Use require to import the `mongoConfig.js` into your `anotherfile.js`

Comment: I need db handle in other files only. I want to keep connection code in db.js file and all other files to use that handle and do respective task. I plan to add many more functions in such other files. hence, I need db handle.

Answer (score 0):

This is basically the classic new JS developer vs async code problem.

```
// When you require db.js, you're kicking off `MongoClient.connect`, which is
// an async function.
var connect = require('./db.js');

// On the very next line when you `getDb`, the connect function callback has not 
// happened yet, and db1 is undefined.
var db1 = connect.getDb(); //=> undefined
```

If you defer the execution of `getDb` to after the connect function has completed, it should work.

```
setTimeout(function () {
  var db1 = connect.getDb(); //=> no longer undefined
}, 5000);
```

In an express app, you're typically running code inside routes, which are async.  As such the database is accessed long after `connect` is called and this becomes a non-issue (which is why if you google you'll see people doing it the exact way you are trying).

---

If you wanted to solve the problem a different way though, you might consider that `MongoClient.connect`, when not passed a callback, returns a promise.  Meaning you could write rewrite your example very simply like:

```
// db.js
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var connectionString = '...';
var connectPromise = MongoClient.connect(connectionString);

exports.getDb = function () {
  return connectPromise;
}

// anotherfile.js
var db = require('./db');
db.getDb().then(function (db) {
  // This callback will never run until the connect promise has
  // resolved and the db is ready.  Calling `getDb` again will not
  // initiate another call to `MongoClient.connect`
  console.log(db);
});
```